# GraphIQL explorer not showing in Gatsby when using gatsby-source-graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby, aws-appsync, graphiql

I'm new to Gatsby and have set up the [aws-appsync-gatsby-sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-appsync-gatsby-sample) project.  The GraphQL data correctly renders in the local site as seen here:

[image]

However, I want to use the GraphIQL explorer to learn how to further manipulate the GraphIQL queries but the "explorer" option that Gatsby typically displays is no longer showing.  Is it because Im using `gatsby-source-graphql`?

**How to I access the GraphIQL explorer to play with this AppSync API data please?
Alternatively, is there another way to access the GraphIQL explorer on my Mac, or online, to access my data?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with gatsby but I'm an engineer on the AppSync team.

As long as you point your GraphiQL app correctly to your AppSync API endpoint, it will work. AppSync GraphQL endpoints are no different than other GraphQL endpoints.

The fastest way to get GraphiQL talking to your AppSync API is:

1. copy the API URL from the Settings pane in the AWS AppSync Console into GraphiQL. It should look like `https://abcdef.appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql`
2. In GraphiQL, add a `X-API-KEY` HTTP request header, and use for value an API key you created from the AppSync Console settings pane. It should start with `da2-xxxxxx`.
3. You should now see the documentation explorer populated, proving the introspection request succeeded.

Comment: I already have GraphIQL working but not the [explorer](https://github.com/OneGraph/graphiql-explorer) Appreciate ether response though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by downloading the latest version of gatsby